# "getting eaten" vs "being eaten"

Tags: grammar, get-be

There was a passage which had a blank, which I had to fill in. 
The sentence was

> ...can save a worm from _______ up by a bird.

I wrote *getting eaten*, but was informed that the correct answer was *being eaten*.

Can both be correct?

Answer (score 4):

Both *can save a worm from being eaten* and *can save a worm from getting eaten* are correct, although the *get-passive* is somewhat more informal. In fact, the *get-passive* is appropriate in this context since it emphasises the negative consequence of the action (*eating*) for the patient (*worm*).

The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p1441-1443) discussion of the *get-passive* includes this extract:

> *Adversity and benefit*: *Get* occurs predominantly in passives
>   representing situations that have an adverse or a beneficial effect on
>   the subject referent, or on someone associated with it, rather than in
>   passives representing purely neutral situations. Typical examples: *Kim
>   got sacked. My watch got stolen*.

Comment: With due respect to the *Cambridge Grammar...* I don't personally consider it good English to say 'he got eaten by an alligator'. The verb 'get' suggests that the subject played some part in arranging whatever it was that happened. I know that millions of Americans use it as second nature, but it is colloquial, largely to North America, I suggest.

Comment: But the sentence to be completed has "... can save a worm from _______ **up** by a bird." The passive *get* in the gerund form  *getting eaten up* sounds a bit weird to my ears.

Comment: @WS2, I suspect that the _get-passive_ is no less common in informal BrE than in AmE.

Comment: @Mary-Lou. (The pre-edited question asked for the correctness of  _being eaten up by a bird_ and _getting eaten by a bird_.) I agree that the inclusion of _up_, in both grammatical variants, makes the sentence sound odd. This may be because, for me, _eat up_ does not collocate naturally with a small single item, such as a worm, that is easy to swallow. Hence _Eat up French Fry_ sounds somewhat odd, but _Eat up your French Fries_ does not

Comment: @Shoe It certainly exists in Britain and is widely used, but as a UK speaker of the language, I am often struck by the frequency with which 'get', 'got' and 'gotten' are used by the average American.  A great deal seems to happen by way of 'get'. Everything from 'How did he get to be Prime Minister?' etc.

Comment: @WS2 'Colloquial to North America' sounds like a contradiction in terms. If more people use  'he got eaten by an alligator' than  'he was eaten by an alligator' (check the relative  populations), perhaps it's we Brits who can more logically be referred to as having a dialect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A country called "England" does have some priority when it comes to defining what is "English". The thing that always puzzles me is why in the USA they do not take pride in calling their language "American"? In fact didn't Webster call his original effort "a Dictionary of the American language"?

Comment: @WS2  "I don't personally consider it good English to say 'He got eaten by an alligator' " is not the same as "I don't personally prefer to say 'He got eaten by an alligator' ". It's good American English, and becoming increasingly acceptable in the UK (CGEL is descriptivist). ELU is not 'BrE'-only, and certainly not '1950's BrE'-only.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As I have noted here before I do not recognise anything called "BrE". Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland, in any case have their own forms of the language. I live in "England", I am an "Englishman", and I speak "English" - even though my East Anglian vowels, if you heard them, you would note do not strictly accord with the Received Pronunciation. It is down to other people to define in their own way what it is they speak, but please don't tell me what I speak.

Comment: @WS2 I always put scare-quotes round _BrE_ (except as here) because I think it's too broad brush. But Americans, including academics, would in general consider 'He got eaten by an alligator' perfectly acceptable, so it's good English (Collins: English is the language spoken in Great Britain and Ireland, the United States, Canada, Australia, and many other countries), even if not idiomatic in the UK (or sub-regions like East Anglia).  Like you, I wouldn't use the get-passive here, but I wouldn't consider someone calling a car bonnet a hood to be using 'not good English'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Was my late mother speaking "good English" when she called the washing-up cloth "a dwile"? I take a fairly liberal view of *hood v bonnet* since both are of relatively recent coinage.  But I hold to the view that there is such a thing as "good English".

Comment: @Shoe It is a good point about the *get passive* being used in non-neutral language. If I say *the car got put in the garage* it suggests something unusual or even sinister has taken place. But *the car was put in the garage* sounds far more routine. It is essentially an American idiom which adds exclamation to a remark.

Comment: @WS2 So being eaten by an alligator is fairly routine?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was seeking to describe the American idiom. I think it is allowed that a non-American can do that.

Answer (score 2):

I repeatedly hear "She will get indicted."  It seems better to say "She will be indicted."  I use "get" for physical objects, as in "I will get the hose (for you)."

Comment: Hello, Gina. Please look at the quality of Shoe's answer to get a feel for the standard of answer ELU prefers.

Comment: +1 You are absolutely right, Gina. However I too recognise @Shoe's answer as valuable. The only thing I would add to it is that the *get passive* is far more common in America than in Britain.

Answer (score -1):

'getting eaten up' refers to the progressive state, the period during which the worm is being eaten

'being eaten up' means the above, too, but also translates to the past state of *having been* eaten up

They are both correct to my eye, at least

Edit: actually on second thoughts 'getting' might be an issue as it doesn't necessarily make sense. Similarly when we say 'I *get* phone calls' 'I *get* lazy" - it's using 'get' in place of verbs that actually make sense, like receive a phone call, become lazy etc.